# Execute a deep link in Windows

Tags: windows, macos, deep-linking

I'm working in an application that uses deeplinks to redirect actions from the user in a website into the app.

In macOS, I can test if the deeplink is working by simply executing in the terminal `open "[deeplink]"`, for instance, `open "my_app_name:import_file=454d1618-fb9b-45ea-b4c3-f32e6200cce4"`. This redirects me to my app and does (or don't) the apropiate action so I can later check the logs, etc.

So, how can I do the same in Windows? How can one "launch" a deep link in Windows? (sorry for my vocabulary, pretty sure it's not correct)

Any method will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows, you can use a variety of methods to launch a deep link (also known as a URI scheme) to test your application. Here are a few methods:

**Method 1: Using Command Prompt or PowerShell**

You can use the `start` command in Command Prompt or PowerShell to launch a URI scheme. For example:

```
start my_app_name:import_file=454d1618-fb9b-45ea-b4c3-f32e6200cce4
```

**Or in PowerShell:**

```
Start-Process "my_app_name:import_file=454d1618-fb9b-45ea-b4c3-f32e6200cce4"
```

**Method 2: Using Run Dialog**

1. Press `Win + R` to open the Run dialog.
2. Type your deep link into the dialog box and press `Enter`. For example:

   ```
   my_app_name:import_file=454d1618-fb9b-45ea-b4c3-f32e6200cce4
   ```

**Method 3: Using a Web Browser**

You can also create a simple HTML file with a hyperlink using the URI scheme and open it with a web browser. For example, create an HTML file with the following content:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Deep Link Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="my_app_name:import_file=454d1618-fb9b-45ea-b4c3-f32e6200cce4">Launch App</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Open this HTML file in a web browser and click the link to launch the deep link.

**And finally - Method 4: Using a Shortcut**

1. Right-click on the desktop and choose `New > Shortcut`.
2. In the location field, type the deep link and click `Next`.

   ```
   my_app_name:import_file=454d1618-fb9b-45ea-b4c3-f32e6200cce4
   ```
3. Give the shortcut a name and click `Finish`.
4. Double-click the shortcut to launch the deep link.

Please make sure that your application is registered to handle the custom URI scheme (`my_app_name` in this case) on Windows. If it's not registered, Windows won't know how to handle the URI scheme and won’t launch your app. You can register a URI scheme by modifying the Windows Registry, which typically happens during the installation of your app.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and quick answer @Marian_Pohl :) I should have thought of method 3, I feel embarassed now jajaja.
I also keep in mind the "URI scheme" term, I didn't know it could be called like that too :)

Comment: Glad I could help! :)